# Background Subtraction MOG in OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have been following some tutorials on OpenCV and many of them reference the `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()`. The issue is that the name or this functionality has changed or been removed. Does anyone know where I can find more current documentation. Does anyone know how to use this feature now?

This is the message I get from python:

> File "OpenCV.py", line 5, in 
>       bgs = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(24*60, 1, 0.9, 0.01)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'

Comment: what's your opencv version?

Comment: if you're using opencv3, the BackgroundSubtractorMOG was moved to https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: I am using version 3. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the Opencv3.0 version, only the BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 was kept as part of the main module as it provided better performance. You can find that here

> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp#L90

Or if looking for BackgroundSubtractorMOG, it has been shifted to the opencv contrib module

> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules